# Programmatically scrolling NSTextView without scrollbar

Tags: cocoa, scroll, textview, scrollbar, scrollview

I'm trying to scroll a textview programmatically using the `scrollToPoint` method. This works fine if the textview has a scrollbar, but if I disable it with `setHasVerticalScroller:NO`, I get some strange results: if I try to scroll using the two-finger gesture after the programmatic scroll, the textview automatically jumps back to the point that was shown before the programmatic scroll. I already tried redrawing the textview and actualizing it, but nothing worked.